Two accounts for me
I  asked this  question from my phone  and  I realized that it represent me  as  a  new contributor.
I  wish to ask the  question from my own account.
In the  past I  frequently used my original  account  via  my phone (as well as my  computer)
But this  is the first time  I  encounter this  problem.
I  would  appreciate if the moderators consider this problem.
Thank you

The help center explains what you can do, if you have access to both accounts. See also: How do I combine my two accounts?, How can I unify/merge two of my accounts? and How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)

@MartinSleziak Great answer, but you should not post it as a comment!

Have a look at this part of the help center: I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
It explains what you should to do merge two accounts.
See also:

How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered) (Meta Stack Exchange)
How do I combine my two accounts? (Meta MathOverflow)
Announcement: New User Merge Policy/Tool (Mathematics Meta)
How can I unify/merge two of my accounts? (Mathematics Meta)

